# Android: TextView is duplicated when I use a custom font

Tags: android, facebook, fonts, textview, custom-font

I want to use a custom font for my android application, but I have a problem.
I got to display the customized font, but the app displays two textes one with the default font-family and another with the custom font-family... it seems to duplicate my TextViews

I followed this tutorial: http://blog.goyello.com/2014/08/01/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-android-apps-and-not-get-fat-3/

However, I also tried with this code in onCreate function of my activity:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bloodmatesIntro1);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BaroqueScript.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

and this code on the xml file

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/bloodmatesIntro1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:text="@string/bloodmates_intro_1"/>
```

what is wrong?

Edit:

I found that the next code (provided by facebook) generates my problem
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#step1:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
} else {
    // Or set the fragment from restored state info
    mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
}
```

How can I use a custom font and login facebook in the same activity?

Comment: No code nothing? How is anyone supposed to help??

Comment: Post the TextView XML and the code where you set Typeface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fragment, I don't know why it duplicates the elements,  so I didn't create the MainFragment class, I followed this tutorial instead http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/android-facebook-login-example/

now, I can use custom fonts and facebook login in the same activity.